# VSCode C++ Include Error . Please update your includePath . MacOS BigSur

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur, xcode-command-line-tools

My Code :-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    cout<<t;
}
```

I am getting an error on the 1st line of the code (#include <bits/stdc++.h>) saying the following :

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

This is what my C++ Properties file looks like:-

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

The Error has been popping up since I have updated my Mac commmand line tools .

I have tried changing my includePath to /inc but that still doesn’t fix the problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: The problem persist even if i change it to #include <iostream>

Comment: @Dev Is it the same error now ? please update the post with new code and new error

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using clang on macOS ?